# Display time zone in photos app for mac

Tags: photos, photos.app

I'm trying to display the time zone that an image was taken in in the Photos app for Mac. I've seen screenshots of this being done but I can't seem to figure it out myself.

[image]

What is a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the capture time on an image, select it and press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or go to Window > Info to see the Info Pane.

[image: Info]

[image: Info pane]

If you want to change that information, select the image you want to correct and then at the top menu select Image > Adjust Date and Time

[image: Photos app - Image > Adjust Date and Time]

This menu will appear that lets you adjust said information.

[image: Adjust Date and Time menu dropdown]

[Source and more info](http://www.macworld.com/article/2882832/heavens-even-more-photos-questions.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've seen that. But I also saw the following screen shot in a forum that clearly shows the time zone in the info box and refers to turning it on. But I can't see  http://i.stack.imgur.com/aaGjq.jpg

Comment: @MikeW, could you post the link to the forum where you saw that also?